# Incorrect number of dimensions in metaMDS and scores (biplot, NMDS ordination) in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, vegan, ggbiplot, biplot

I am trying to make a biplot in R using the vegan package:

```
shared_tbl <-read_tsv("data/andok.shared")
```

my data is like this table:

| Group | Blastocatellales | Frankiales | Cyanobacteriales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sample1 | 319 | 2563 | 546 |
| sample2 | 4114 | 657 | 986 |
| sample3 | 1463 | 123 | 85 |
| sample4 | 158 | 367 | 631 |

```
shared_df <- shared_tbl%>%
   column_to_rownames("Group")

#make a distance matrix
andok_dist <- avgdist(shared_df, sample = 1156)

#nmds ordination
set.seed(1996020)
andok_nmds <- metaMDS(andok_dist)
scores(andok_nmds)
```

and then I got the error:
**Error in x$species[, choices, drop = FALSE] :**
**incorrect number of dimensions**

A solution has reached in metaMDS after setting the seed.

I made my steps according to Pat Schloss https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_EjNR6YdnGM&t=45s%5C half years ago, when the whole code ran without any errors.

Comment: Try to create a reproducible example so we can help you. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added a table similar to mine, thank you for your comment! :)

Comment: which line is the one giving you a problem? Your code works with my dummy data I created.

Comment: After scores(andok_nmds) I got an error:
Error in x$species[, choices, drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may occur in **vegan** 2.6-2. It was fixed in the latest release version 2.6-4. Please upgrade your **vegan**. If you cannot or will not upgrade **vegan**, explicitly skip species scores (that you do not have when input data are dissimilarities which have no information on species):

```
scores(andok_mds, display="sites")
```

The problems was introduced when the `scores` function gained option of directly producing "tidy" scores for **ggplot2** graphics.